# Set background color of UITableView section header to white and make it opaque

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, sectionheader

I've tried every solution proposed by the community for the background color problem of tableview section headers so I'm now reaching out for help. 
I have custom section headers that float (plain style of the table view) and I'd like each header to be displayed on top of the rows. When I scroll the table view, the header background is transparent, and it shows the content of the scrolling row. In order for this to stop, I've tried the following:

```
    -(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
TableHeader *header = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:@"TableHeader"];
header.event = [events objectAtIndex:section];
[header.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[header.contentView setOpaque:YES];
[header drawHeader];
return header;
}
```

Nothing changes, and the header is still transparent. Has anyone faced that problem?

Comment: Try adding a view that fills the `contentView`.  Set its background color.  Add your subviews to that view, and not the `contentView`.

Comment: @RohitPradhan: logically, how could that possibly help?

Comment: @RohitPradhan I want the header to be opaque, setting the property to NO it would become transparent. I still tried it but it didn't change anything. Also, i tried setting the background color to black but it didn't seem to work

Comment: @Avi it still doesn't change anything, even though all the other properties get set up correctly, this one won't..

Comment: Edit: I created an IBOutlet for the UIView proposed by @Avi in my xib file and set the properties background color and opaque there. it worked

Comment: Did u guys found any solution..? I'm stuck due to the same scenario